# Strange trait behavior in PHP

Tags: php, traits

Consider the following. I have 4 files.

**sub.php**

```
<?php

class sub extends main {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo "constructor in sub<br>";
    }
}
```

**trait.php**

```
<?php

trait t1 {
    function tProcess() {
        echo "in tprocess in trait<br>";
    }
}
```

**main1.php**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
require_once 'sub.php';
require_once 'trait.php';

class main {
    function __construct() {
        echo "constructor in main<br>";
    }

    function process() {
        echo "doing something in main<br>";
    }
}

$t = new sub();
$t->process();
```

and **main2.php**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
require_once 'sub.php';
require_once 'trait.php';

class main {
    use t1;
    function __construct() {
        echo "constructor in main<br>";
    }

    function process() {
        echo "doing something in main<br>";
    }
}

$t = new sub();
$t->process();
```

main1 works as expected, but main2 gives me a ***Fatal error: Class 'main' not found*** error. Just including the trait is changing something in the behavior of how the file inclusions work.

Comment: What is t1?  Did you mislabel your trait?  Also, where are you including the trait?

Comment: my bad, had some copy paste issues, corrected them both now

Comment: I think you just have an require once ordering issue, but I cant be 100% sure.

Comment: I thought so too initially but that isnt the case since the first one works (when not including the trait).

Answer (score -1):

Yup, it is just an include ordering issue.  This is one of the countless reasons people use the autoloader.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
require_once 'trait.php';

class main {
    use t1;
    function __construct() {
        echo "constructor in main<br>";
    }

    function process() {
        echo "doing something in main<br>";
    }
}

require_once 'sub.php';
$t = new sub();
$t->process();
```